# TypeError: 'ChatCompletionMessageToolCall' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, llama-index

I'm following Llama Index's documentation, which seems out-of-date. This seems to be true of just about everything in the LLM space. I've checked OpenAI's [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/openai/1.1.1/) and I can't seem to find the right API. Maybe I'm missing something?

When I run `main.py`, this is the output:

```
Hello! How can I assist you today?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/Documents/openai-agent/main.py", line 80, in <module>
    print(agent.chat("What is 2123 * 215123"))
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/me/Documents/openai-agent/main.py", line 54, in chat
    function_message = self._call_function(tool_call)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/me/Documents/openai-agent/main.py", line 62, in _call_function
    id_ = tool_call["id"]
          ~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^
TypeError: 'ChatCompletionMessageToolCall' object is not subscriptable
```

Here's the code:

```
from typing import Sequence, List
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import json
from llama_index.llms.openai import OpenAI
from llama_index.core.llms import ChatMessage
from llama_index.core.tools import BaseTool, FunctionTool
import nest_asyncio

nest_asyncio.apply()
load_dotenv()

def multiply(a: int, b: int) -> int:
    """Multiplies two integers and returns the result integer"""
    return a * b

multiply_tool = FunctionTool.from_defaults(fn=multiply)

def add(a: int, b: int) -> int:
    """Adds two integers and returns the result integer"""
    return a + b

add_tool = FunctionTool.from_defaults(fn=add)


class MyOpenAIAgent:
    def __init__(
        self,
        tools: Sequence[BaseTool] = [],
        llm: OpenAI = OpenAI(temperature=0, model="gpt-3.5-turbo-0613"),
        chat_history: List[ChatMessage] = [],
    ) -> None:
        self._llm = llm
        self._tools = {tool.metadata.name: tool for tool in tools}
        self._chat_history = chat_history

    def reset(self) -> None:
        self._chat_history = []

    def chat(self, message: str) -> str:
        chat_history = self._chat_history
        chat_history.append(ChatMessage(role="user", content=message))
        tools = [
            tool.metadata.to_openai_tool() for _, tool in self._tools.items()
        ]

        ai_message = self._llm.chat(chat_history, tools=tools).message
        additional_kwargs = ai_message.additional_kwargs
        chat_history.append(ai_message)

        tool_calls = ai_message.additional_kwargs.get("tool_calls", None)
        # parallel function calling is now supported
        if tool_calls is not None:
            for tool_call in tool_calls:
                function_message = self._call_function(tool_call)
                chat_history.append(function_message)
                ai_message = self._llm.chat(chat_history).message
                chat_history.append(ai_message)

        return ai_message.content

    def _call_function(self, tool_call: dict) -> ChatMessage:
        id_ = tool_call["id"]
        function_call = tool_call["function"]
        tool = self._tools[function_call["name"]]
        output = tool(**json.loads(function_call["arguments"]))
        return ChatMessage(
            name=function_call["name"],
            content=str(output),
            role="tool",
            additional_kwargs={
                "tool_call_id": id_,
                "name": function_call["name"],
            },
        )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    agent = MyOpenAIAgent(tools=[multiply_tool, add_tool])
    print(agent.chat("Hi"))
    print(agent.chat("What is 2123 * 215123"))
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Here's the updated working code as of **3.26.1991**:

```
from typing import Sequence, List
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import json
from llama_index.llms.openai import OpenAI
from llama_index.core.llms import ChatMessage
from llama_index.core.tools import BaseTool, FunctionTool
from llama_index.agent.openai import OpenAIAgent
from llama_index.llms.openai import OpenAI

import nest_asyncio

nest_asyncio.apply()
load_dotenv()

def multiply(a: int, b: int) -> int:
    """Multiplies two integers and returns the result integer"""
    return a * b

multiply_tool = FunctionTool.from_defaults(fn=multiply)

def add(a: int, b: int) -> int:
    """Adds two integers and returns the result integer"""
    return a + b

add_tool = FunctionTool.from_defaults(fn=add)

llm = OpenAI(model="gpt-3.5-turbo-0613")
agent = OpenAIAgent.from_tools(
    [multiply_tool, add_tool], llm=llm, verbose=True
)

class MyOpenAIAgent:
    def __init__(
        self,
        tools: Sequence[BaseTool] = [],
        llm: OpenAI = OpenAI(temperature=0, model="gpt-3.5-turbo-0613"),
        chat_history: List[ChatMessage] = [],
    ) -> None:
        self._llm = llm
        self._tools = {tool.metadata.name: tool for tool in tools}
        self._chat_history = chat_history

    def reset(self) -> None:
        self._chat_history = []

    def chat(self, message: str) -> str:
        chat_history = self._chat_history
        chat_history.append(ChatMessage(role="user", content=message))
        tools = [
            tool.metadata.to_openai_tool() for _, tool in self._tools.items()
        ]

        ai_message = self._llm.chat(chat_history, tools=tools).message
        additional_kwargs = ai_message.additional_kwargs
        chat_history.append(ai_message)

        tool_calls = ai_message.additional_kwargs.get("tool_calls", None)
        # parallel function calling is now supported
        if tool_calls is not None:
            for tool_call in tool_calls:
                function_message = self._call_function(tool_call)
                chat_history.append(function_message)
                ai_message = self._llm.chat(chat_history).message
                chat_history.append(ai_message)

        return ai_message.content

    def _call_function(self, tool_call) -> ChatMessage:
        id_ = tool_call.id
        function_name = tool_call.function.name
        tool_arguments_json = tool_call.function.arguments

        tool_arguments = json.loads(tool_arguments_json)
        tool = self._tools[function_name]

        output = tool(**tool_arguments)

        return ChatMessage(
        name=function_name,
        content=str(output),
        role="tool",
        additional_kwargs={
            "tool_call_id": id_,
            "name": function_name,
        },
    )

if __name__ == "__main__":
     agent = MyOpenAIAgent(tools=[multiply_tool, add_tool])
     print(agent.chat("Hi"))
     print(agent.chat("What is 2123 * 215123"))
```